# how to create trigger on derived table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created two tables `customer` and `orders` and I have already inserted some data in `customer` table but nothing is in orders table. Now I want to create a trigger on orders table that would copy only the `id` column ( which is defined in customer table as `primary key`) in orders table of `o_id` ( which is defined as `foreign key` in orders table ).

I want to check my created trigger and fix it if you find any error in it.

My trigger for orders table :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_order
       BEFORE INSERT
       ON orders
       FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       SELECT ID
       INTO   :NEW.o_id
       FROM   customer;
    END;
```

Thanks.

Comment: you have indeed a problem. The select `SELECT ID  FROM   customer;` will select many rows, not one. You should add a where clause to specify what row to get.

Comment: pls add the definitions for both tables customer and orders because the answers go crazy.

Comment: No trigger necessary: `insert into orders (o_id) select id from customer`

Comment: guys in short it should work like " on update cascade " as some database don't support it so we have to find some other way that is with the help of  triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a trigger on orders table that would copy only the
>   id column
>   you can start doing like this , (by the way I didnt understand where you want to use your derived table ? what is the query)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_order
       BEFORE INSERT
       ON orders
       FOR EACH ROW
       declare cnt number (3);
    BEGIN

    select count(1) into cnt from customer where id=:new.id; // its is checking
    if cnt=0 then
    insert into customer (id) values (:new.id);
    end if;
    // you can add raise error here 
    END;
/
```

Comment: i want to copy this id of customer table into o_id of orders table just like " on update cascade " works why don't you understand :(

Comment: @AhtishamChishti when you insert `id` into table customer you want the same id to be inserted into table order .. is that what you want ? I am trying to understand you

Comment: @AhtishamChishti try somthing like this

Answer (score 0):

you want to copy a value from `customer` table to `orders` table with help of trigger so firstly you will be needing to create the trigger on `customer`table not on `orders`table ,since for every insert done in the customer table the trigger will be fired once which will insert a value in orders table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_order
 AFTER INSERT
 ON customer
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO orders
           (o_id)
  SELECT :NEW.ID
  FROM   customer;
END;
```

Comment: you didn't understand me man i want to create trigger on orders table so that whenever i insert some data in orders table it should automatically copy the id value in customer to o_id of order table

Comment: Ahh okay.. so there must be a relation between the customer and orders table.. since you want to fetch the data from customer table. on what basis you are fetching the data from the customer? what is the specific condition?

Comment: @AhtishamChishti what do you want to copied data ?

Comment: @dawn " id " column of customer is defined as primary key & " o_id "  column of orders is defined as foreign key now i want to copy value of " id" into "o_id" ( of orders table )  btw i have created sequence " cus_seq " as well on customer table of column " id ".

Comment: @Ahtisham - yes, but if there are two customers in the customer table, by what means do we determine which customer ID to select for this Order that you are inserting? There must be some way to know, and you aren't telling us, so how are we supposed to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a rule for finding the customer.
For example:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_order
       BEFORE INSERT
       ON orders
       FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       SELECT c.ID
       INTO   :NEW.o_id
       FROM   customer c
       WHERE c.customer_code = :NEW.customer_code; 
    END;
```

Comment: c is just an alias for the table